# Unable to use private methods in NSObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, model, nsobject

I have created a subclass of `NSObject` to be used as a Model.

Within this I have some public methods which are accessible outside of this.

Within the implementation file I also have some Private methods like this:

```
+(void)publicMethod {
    // I am public
}


-(void)privateMethod {
    // I am private 
}
```

However, I am unable to call the private method from within the public method. I.e. the following does not work:

```
[self privateMethod];
```

Is this expected behaviour? Should all the methods in my NSObject subclass (used as a model) be public?

Comment: You can't call instance methods from a class method (at least not on `self`). Did you actually mean to make `publicMethod` a class method (that is what the `+` means)?

Comment: @rmaddy - Thanks, I am looking to setup a model. The model is used for some networking updates to a MBSAAS. The methods do not really relate to an object as such so there is no init etc, I have subclasses NSObject. What would be the correct approach for a model setup? That I am able to create public/private methods that can be called from each other within the class.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: Remark that this answer is not complete. The question deals with instance methods calling class methods, which I did not catch when I was writing the answer. But even though it does not answer the question, it's still an example on how to mimic the use of public and private methods in Objective-C.*

---

In Objective-C there is no such thing as public and private methods, but you can "hide" instance methods by not putting them in the public header file.

This is the way Apple does it. NSObject, UIView, NSString, etc., has a bunch of "private" methods. That being they are not private. They are simply not exposed in the header file you include in your app.

If your class has an instance or class method that is not visible to the outside world, you can still just declare it yourself - if you know the prototype - in your code and then access them.

The way I do it is by creating two header files. One for public methods and one for private. Let's say this is a public library, I will only include the header files with the "public" methods for other developers to use.

On the other hand, inside my project, I can include the "private" header, which holds both the private and the public methods, and I have access to everything I need.

An example is this class, which has to methods: `foo` and `bar`. `foo` is public and `bar` is private.

The "public" header - which is called `MyCustomClass.h` would look like this:

```
@interface MyCustomClass

- (void)foo;

@end
```

Then I create a class extension in another header file - which is called `MyCustomClass+Private.h`, and it looks like this. This is also a good place to put your instance variables, so they too won't be exposed to the "outside world".

```
@import "MyPublicClass.h"

@interface MyPublicClass () {

    NSInteger _myIvar;

}

- (void)bar;

@end
```

Now in the class implementation - which is called `MyCustomClass.m` I implement everything. Remark that I am including the private header file.

```
@import "MyPublicClass+Private.h"

@implementation MyPublicClass

- (void)bar { /* Private Method */

    /* Do something */

}

- (void)foo {

    [self bar];

}

@end
```

## Solution

Now whenever I subclass MyCustomClass I first and foremost also create a private header for that class - which imports the private header of it's superclass. The public header of the subclass only imports it's superclass's public header.

This way both `foo` and `bar` are exposed to subclasses, but not to outsiders - as you would not put your private headers in your library - if that's what you are making.

## A remark on your example

In the old days, you could do what you do, and get away with a compiler warning. But nowadays ARC is not satisfied, and throws a compiler error. This is because ARC needs to know the return type, so it can do release/retain on it, in order to properly manage your app's memory.

## Simpler solution

A simpler way of doing it could also be to just throw the superclass extension - with the superclass's "private" method prototypes - in your subclass's implementation. But this has the drawback of you needing to go through every place you put the extension if you change your superclass's behaviour down the road. So I wouldn't recommend it.

## Final

**Hope this clarifies and helps you out. Good luck!**

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the indepth answer, However I think it might have gone a little off topic. My question is more towards how a Model should be setup. I need a Model which will handle the data part of the application, mainly some network calls and updates etc. At present I subclass NSObject for my models and create methods public/private just by adding them to the header or not (which is enough in depth as I need). However, as they subclass NSObject I have to make them class methods (+) to then call [self methodName]. Is this the correct approach for a model layout?

Comment: I guess there would not be any form of alloc/init needed for these as they are not actually Objects, it is a model. That is what I am unsure about. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your class method vs. instance method now. It is easy to not catch those plus and minuses. What you are doing you cannot do. You can always call class methods from instance methods, but not the other way around. Instance methods needs - as their name suggests - an instance. You could use the singleton model: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/ .

Comment: I have added a disclaimer to the answer, which points out, that it does not fully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `publicMethod` is a class method. So `self` is the class in this method, not an instance. And the class doesn't implement `privateMethod` because it's an instance method.

Comment: So really as it is a model all methods should be class methods. I would then access them from the other methods using [self privateMethod]. Then by not adding the method names to the header file would make them ''private'' as far as the word private is used in objc.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using any class methods other than maybe a constructor. You're right about the public / private part.

Comment: How would a model layout be setup correctly then? I used a subclass of NSObject just as a basic. The methods are not necessarily associated to an object, but do some network updates so should be in a model. How else would this be setup without any class methodS?

Comment: A model is for data storage. Network comma should be in / managed by a controller. The controller could be a singleton and the owner of your model.

Comment: Its not as such network, although there are some network calls. It is to update a mobile storage like Parse.com. So I create a model to handle these checks and updates, which may/may not be the correct approach and I am sure there are arguments about both... The question is really how the model should be setup. Should it be a subclass of something or not? If not do you have any information that is useful on how these should be setup? And how I would call [self methodName] without them being class methods. Do singletons not implement a bunch of class methods?